# What Is The Difference Between Core And Noncore Modules In A CMS

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-modules

1-What Is The Difference Between Core And NonCore Modules In A CMS?

2-Specialy In Drupal What Are Core Modules And NonCore Modules?

Thanks For Your Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.1. The "**core modules**" are the modules that are included in the Drupal installation pack. They are the basic features that offer you a starting kit. You can find them in the `./modules` folder. But you **can't alter them** (it is not a good practice).

1.2. "**Non-core modules**", or "contributed modules" are **additional** features, pieces of code, that extend (or override) the core modules functionnalities. They are developed and maintained by the **community** (you and me). You can add them to your Drupal site like little bricks by the admin interface (modules menu) or manually (download and copy the code in the right folder).

You can also develop your **own personal module** (we will talk about "custom module") if you don't find a contributed module that suits you. If you're searching for classical feature, be sure that a contrib module already exists. Don't reinvent the wheel ;-)

You will find these modules in `./sites/all/modules` folders (`/custom` for yours or `/contrib` for the community's).

2.1. There is a list of all **core modules** here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1283408

2.2. There is an "infinity" of **contributed modules** and you can search them here: https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module/index

Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal:

> Get started by downloading the official Drupal core files. These official releases come bundled with a variety of modules and themes to give you a good starting point to help build your site. **Drupal core includes basic community features like blogging, forums, and contact forms**, and can be easily extended by downloading other contributed modules and themes.

Non-core modules are the extra bells and whistles that you can install to give your site more features. Non-core modules are frequently contributed and maintained by users, rather than the Drupal team.